# How to get form data from JSP forms and send it to database controller and RestController and display it back in another JSP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, controller, spring-restcontroller

I am doing a spring boot project where I have to use JSP, Controller and RestController along with SQL database.
When I try to map the POST method from JSP into a controller, either it is showing null value or showing error.

the jsp page is:

```
    <h3>To add an Item:</h3>
    <form action="additem" method="post">
        Enter Color  name: <input type="text" name="color"><br>
        Enter Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br>
        Enter Price: <input type="number" name="price"><br>
        Enter Shoe Name: <input type="text" name="shoe_name"><br>
        Enter Size: <input type="text" name="size"><br>
        Enter User Group: <input type="text" name="user_group"><br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

The controller is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/additem", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertItem(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "shoe_name") String shoename, ShoeData data) {
        data = resource.createShoe(shoename, data);
        model.addAttribute("totalShoes", data);
        return "warehouse";
    }
```

the restful controller is:

```
@RestController
public class RestfulResource {

    @Autowired
    private ShoeService shoeService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/{shoename}/shoelist")
    public ShoeData createShoe(@PathVariable String shoename, @Valid 
   @RequestBody ShoeData data) {
        ShoeData saveData = shoeService.insertData(data);
        return saveData;
    }
```

the JSP page to display the result:

```
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${totalShoes}"> 

            <tr>
                <td>${item.id}</td>
                <td>${item.color}</td>
                <td>${item.description}</td>
                <td>${item.price}</td>
                <td>${item.shoeName}</td>
                <td>${item.size}</td>
                <td>${item.userGroup}</td>              
            </tr>
            
    </c:forEach>
```

the error is:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Validation failed for object='shoeData'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'shoeData' on field 'price': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.shoeData.price,typeMismatch.price,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [shoeData.price,price]; arguments []; default message [price]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'price'; For input string: ""]

the restcontroller is working fine and able to POST data through advanced REST client. But, I am not able to get data from form into the database and display it in the JSP page as it is showing the above error. How can I get ShoeData entity inside the controller method?

Comment: *When I try to map the POST method from JSP into a controller, either it is showing null value or showing error.*  - You should be using POST when posting from a form - **tell us what the error is** (edit your question and add the stacktrace)

Comment: now, i changed the form method and also the controller request method as POST. When I try to submit the form nothing is displaying and I did a print in console for the variable and it is showing null.

Comment: why would you expect `ShoeData data = new ShoeData();` to contain valid data?  `data.getShoeName();` has not been set to anything and is likely to be null.

Comment: Then, how can I pass the parameter for resource.createShoe()? please help me understand.

Comment: Did you notice that your method accepts `Model model` - have a look at what it contains.  You are not even using it.

Comment: can you explain where I have to make changes. should I send model as a parameter in the createShoe?

Comment: `public ResponseEntity createShoe(@PathVariable String shoename, @Valid @RequestBody ShoeData data)`  - read your code.

Comment: yes I read. The createShoe method has 2 parameters. So, how can I use this method in the controller class. I have to mention the methods so i did. Please could you elaborate.

Comment: I think the key thing is to get the data from the Model and create a ShoeData object, no?

Comment: yes you are right. I used Model.getAttribute("shoe_name"), but what can  i do for the whole object, which is ShoeData. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own.

The controller class is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/additem", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertItem(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "shoe_name") String shoename, ShoeData data) {
        List<ShoeData> convertedData = new ArrayList<ShoeData>();
        convertedData.add(data);
        System.out.println(data.getClass());
        model.addAttribute("totalShoes", convertedData);
        return "warehouse";
    }
```

Restful controller class is as below:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/{shoename}/shoelist")
    public ShoeData createShoe(@PathVariable String shoename, @Valid @RequestBody ShoeData data) {
        ShoeData saveData = shoeService.insertData(data);
        return saveData;
    }
```

I still got error that there is type mismatch between the price variable in model class which was int but the method was trying to covnert to String which caused the error, and so I changed the type of the price variable to String for now. I will identify the root cause and update soon.